# Did Google penalize my site due to interlinking backlinks around same company website and blog?

Tags: backlinks, link-building

I’m handling two websites in my company and both have more than 18,000 backlinks (I checked it through my GWT) and most of the links are coming from a Blogspot blog. I checked each and every backlink and I found that one particular blog contains most of our links.

That blog has been handled by our colleague and he had posted more than 1080 posts. Each and every post contains my website’s link. That blog is related to cricket and mine is about boxing and track and field. At the end of each post my links have been placed by comma separation which looks odd for me because all the posts are related to cricket and mine is about boxing and track and field.

He placed anchor texts as *Boxing gloves* and *Athletic Gear* in the last line of each post and from that anchor text my website has been getting backlink.

After Google Last penguin 2.0 update I found that both of my websites lost ranking on Google. All my main keywords gone to 100th page (before Penguin update they were on first two pages) including *Boxing Gloves* and *Athletic Gear*.

Now my doubt is about the backlinks from that Blogspot blog. Did Google penalize my site because of that backlinks (interlinking around same company website and blog)? Does inbound links from cricket related page to boxing page is a link spam?

See this image for more info:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, if the proportion of backlinks from this website is 1080 over 18000, there is no reason why Google penalized you for this. Moreover, even if the subject of the two websites are not very related, they are about sports both.

In the worst case, it considers these links as low weigth for PageRank because they are all in the same website but I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

I work for a company that runs a bunch of divisions, each with their own store. On the top of all the pages in the menu bar, there is a dropdown of links called "jump to another store". Due to the compounding effect, this means that each domain has a **net +40,000 urls backlinking** to it from the other divisions, via the jump-to-store menu.

Have we noticed any penalty from this? No. Google has never warned us in GWT either. Even on new divisions/sites, they are not penalized for being spammy or whatever. Perhaps this is because they are so related to eachother, or perhaps because of these steps:

- Keep it consistant, 1 menu is the only spot to do interlinking on every page.
- Authorize and verify your domain(s) under singular Google apps.
- Authorize google places then set publisher rel/RDF based on that.
- Set organization RDF to tell Google its a subsidiary, make it match the places info.

This isn't really the same as what your situation is, but its reassurance that mass backlinking like this is probably OK, assuming you aren't abusing/spamming it.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems as an over optimization of anchor text penguin penalty. You have 1080 links all containing the same anchor text pointing to your website, links which are not contextual and not relevant.  1080 posts each one containing the same link is HIGHLY spammy and very unnatural.

If I were you I would ask him to delete all of those links as they are DEFINITELY not bringing you any value and most likely are doing harm to your sites backlink profile.